# Sudden load spikes in Cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra

We recently started having problems with our Cassandra cluster. Maybe someone has ideas on how to fix this. We're running Cassandra 3.11.7 on a 40 node cluster. We are using replication factor = 3 and read/write at consistency level QUORUM.

Recently, a single node experienced a sudden spike in CPU load which then last for a while. During that period, we can observe a lot of dropped and queued MUTATIONs. If we restart Cassandra on the problematic node, one or two other nodes start to suffer of the same problem. We have examined log files and access patterns and have not yet been able to find the reason.

What could be the most common reasons for such behaviour? Where should we take a closer look? Has anyone already had similar experiences?

Answer (score 1):

> If we restart Cassandra on the problematic node, one or two other nodes start to suffer of the same problem.

First of all, when a single node presents a problem, restarting it generally achieves nothing.  If anything, you'll clear the JVM heap...which will be quickly repopulated upon startup.  Seriously, don't expect restarting a node to fix anything.

> Has anyone already had similar experiences?

Yes, several times.  For things not Cassandra related:

- Are you in a cloud environment?  Run `iostat` and look for things like high percentages of `iowait` and `steal`.  Sometimes shared resources don't play well with others.  If you don't have `iostat`, get it (`yum install -y sysstat`).
- Check cron for all users.  We once had an issue with a file integrity checker getting installed as a part of our base image, and it did exactly what you are talking about.

> What could be the most common reasons for such behaviour? Where should we take a closer look?

For Cassandra related issues, I see a few possibilities:

- Repairs.  Check if the node is running a repair.  You can see Merkle Tree calculations with `nodetool compactionstats` and repair streams with `nodetool netstats`.
- Compactions.  Check `nodetool compactionstats`.  If this is it, you can try lowering your compaction throughput so that it doesn't affect normal operations.
- Garbage Collection.  Check the `gc.log.*` files.  If it's GC, it can usually be fixed by reading up on and adjusting the GC settings.  If there isn't anyone on your team who is a JVM GC expert, I recommend using G1GC as it removes a lot of the guesswork.

Do note that everything I mentioned above can *never* be fixed with a reboot.  In fact, it's likely it'll pick right back up where it left off.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the hints. It helped us to reduce the problem map. As we don't have issues with cron, repairs or compactions, we had a closer look at our client queries using `nodetool toppartitions` on the problematic nodes. Eventually we found out that the reason is some really huge data we're constantly updating due to some bug in our application logic. After fixing this bug the load spikes disappeared.